# How do i refresh a UIView when Orientation happens?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My code goes like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self setGridView];
}
-(void)setGridView
{
  CGRect frame; 
  frame .origin.x=0;
  frame.origin.y=20;
  frame.size.width=GRID_WEIGHT;
  frame.size.height=GRID_HEIGHT;
  GridView *ObjGridView=[[GridView alloc]initWithFrame:frame]; 

  [[NSBundle mainBundle ] loadNibNamed:@"GridView" owner:ObjGridView options:nil];
  [ObjGridView setGridViewFrame:frame];

  [self.view addSubview:ObjGridView.GridCellView];
  frame .origin.x+=GRID_WEIGHT;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return YES;
}
```

This code adds a subview to a view and sets the frame

My problem:
1-How do i refresh my view when Orientation(landscape or portrait) happens,
because  i set  the frame  of subview in the lanscape mode and i wants to use the sane view in my portrait view also .(basically where do i call this  -(void)setGridView delegate method)?

2-How do i know, my subview exceeding the bound of the view,so that i can handle the subview in my setGridView method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Below method will call automatically whenever your orientation changes. Do the necessary changes according to each orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {}

else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {} 

else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {} 

else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {}

return YES;

}
```

2.You should know the width and height of your views and set the frames accordingly. That is not a big deal.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning the ins and outs of iOS Application development myself, so please forgive me for the brevity of my response.

I believe you may be able to find the answer to your issue within the section titled 'Responding to Orientation Changes' within this document on Apple's Developer Resources:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

I hope this helps you deduce a resolution to your issue.

Comment: can any body suggest me that how do i  know, my subview exceeding the bound of the view,so that i can handel the subview in my method ?

Comment: help me Guys ,to my above problem

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(OrientationChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Method for notify you that Orientation Changed:-

```
-(void)OrientationChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation Orientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

    if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    }
    else if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your questionsL

With regard to resizing on orientation change:
If you set your springs and struts accordingly it should autoresize automatically, alternatively you can do this in code as per deamonsarea's answer

To check if a view is exceeding the bounds of the superview use CGRectContainsRect
something like.

```
CGRect frame0 = self.view.bounds;
CGRect frame1 = ObjGridView.frame;
if(CGRectContainsRect(frame0,frame1)==NO){
  NSLog(@"exceeds bounds")
}
```

Also noticed you are not calling [super viewDidLoad] and this line

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle ] loadNibNamed:@"GridView" owner:ObjGridView options:nil];
```

loads a new instance of the view but you are not refering to it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking for a way to react to orientation change inside the UIView itself. In case anyone else comes along...

If you want to react to orientation change inside a `UIView`, rather than a `UIViewController` (for encapsulation or other reasons), you can use this method:

```
class MyView: UIView {
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    println("orientation or other bounds-impacting change")
  }
}
```